# Which UART is used on the Explorer 16 development board with PIC32?

Tags: pic, microchip

I am trying to use "PIC32mz2048ech100" on "explorer16" to get "UART" communication. Can anyone let me know which uart channel(from 1 to 6)of PIC32 microcontroller is connected to explorer 16.

Answer (score 2):

The UART1 is used.

But beware, the Explorer 16 board uses two 74HCT4053 analog multiplexers to simplify the con-
nections between itself and any daughter boards. U6 and U7 provide active control of 
the cross-wire capability on SPI1 and UART1, with a hardware flow control signal 
provided by three I/O pins.

Comment: Thank u mike for your reply. do u mean uart1 of explorer to uart1 of pic32 microcontroller ?

Comment: UART1 of the controller. Please have a look into zhe manual, the multiplexers are a little bit tricky.

Comment: could you please forward me the schematics of Explorer16 board it will be a great help if you send me that.Thank you in advance

Comment: Have a look: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/50001589b.pdf . Have a look at microchip.com

Comment: this is the code i am using but i am getting junk values in hyper terminal       
 http://aidanmocke.com/blog/2018/08/29/uart/

Comment: If you are getting anything in HT you are working with the correct UART. Thats fine. Double check baudrate. Please remember HT displays only ASCII characters.

Comment: Thank you mike for the reply...i am using baud rate formula =((25000000/(9600*16))-1 as PIC32MZ2048ech100 uses PBCLK2 and i am also making BRGH=0 still i am not able to get correct data on HT.

Comment: I got it mike thank you for your time. The problem was uart was taking daughter board osc frequency not explorer 16 frequency.

Comment: great! have fun the board.

Comment: Hi i am trying to work usart with harmony in mplab transmitter is working n not receiving . kindly let me know where i am wrong.

Comment: if(!DRV_USART_ReceiverBufferIsEmpty(appData.handleUSART5))
                {
                    /* Read the received character */
                    app_rx_buf[appData.rx_count] = DRV_USART_ReadByte(appData.handleUSART5);}